# Little Endian - Memory content/address

Tags: binary

Consider a system that has a byte-addressable memory organized in 32-bit words according to the big-endian scheme. A program reads ASCII characters entered at a keyboard and stores them in successive byte locations starting at location 1000.

Show the contents of the two memory words at locations 1000 and 1004 after the name johnson has been entered. Write this in the little-endian scheme.

What I got was:

[NULL, n], [o, s], [n,h],  [o,j]
00, 6E     6F, 73  6E, 68  6F, 6A

I just want to know if this is correct and if not, what I did wrong.

Thank you all!

Comment: Ignacio Vasquez-Abrams's answer is correct, but just a comment on your tentative answer: if your machine has 32-bit words, you should be "packing" 4 characters into a word, not two, as it appears you are doing with your notation.  The correct answer should be [6a,6f,68,6e],[73,6f,6e,00].  It looks like maybe it's a trick question, since I think a lot of people might reverse the byte order in the two words when the see "little endian" in the problem.

Comment: Hey Ray! Thank you very much for your comment.

I was confused because I saw that Endian has the most significant byte with the least byte address and vice versa for Little Endian.

Does the mean that both little endian/big endian answers are the same?

For big endian I got:
character: j o h n s o n [null]
content in hex: 6A, 6F, 68, 6E, 73, 6F, 6E, 00
byte address: 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007

Little endian:

Comment: The point is that endianness applies to word or larger size quantities, not byte-sized ones.  So if I wanted to store the value 7 at address 1000, and the value 260 (that's 104 in hex) at address 1004, then in _little endian_ the two words would be 07000000 and 04010000, but in big endian we would have 00000007 and 00000104.  So you only see a difference for multi-byte quantities.  ASCII characters are encoded in one byte each so those look the same either way.  Ditto for things like UTF-8 which explicitly use _byte-sized_ chunks.

Comment: While byte data will be stored the same way, it looks to me that the question ("show the contents of the memory **words**") is asking for something akin to `*((uint32_t*)0x1000)` and `*((uint32_t*)0x1004)`, which *would* give different result in the Big vs. Little Endian cases.  It would be appropriate to write a result of that sort in hex, perhaps with a comma between the words but *not* between the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as endianes for storing a single byte (such as an ASCII character). Endianes only comes into play when a value is represented as multiple bytes. So for example, storing a sequence of bytes is the same in little- and big-endian, only the representation of the bytes are different. For example, take the number 3 735 928 559 (or 0xdeadbeef in hex notation) and store that as a 32-bit word (e.g., an int) at memory location 1000 will give:

```
ADR: 1000 1001 1002 1004  
BE:   de   ad   be   ef  
LE:   ef   be   ad   de
```

So, if you were to actually represent your ASCII character as a 32-bit word you would get:

```
[0, 0, 0, 6a], [0, 0, 0, 6f], ... or,  
[6a, 0, 0, 0], [6f, 0, 0, 0], ...
```

for BE and LE respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I find this question quite confusing.

`byte` is normally defined as the smallest addressable unit so saying that a machine has byte-addressable memory just tells nothing: every machine has byte-addressable memory because that's the definition of what a byte is, what can change is how many bits is a byte.

If the question is talking about a 32-bit byte machine (I know they exists, but I personally used only machines with 8-bit and 16-bit bytes) then it's not clear what role is playing endian-ness given that no multibyte processing is needed for storing ASCII.
What is often done in large-byte machines is however storing multiple characters per byte to save space (not necessarily a 16-bit byte machine is "big": the one I know is a DSP with a very limited amount of memory) but this seems unrelated to the question and there so "standard" way to do so anyway.

If instead the question assumes that a byte is always 8 bit by definition and talks about storing ASCII chars then once again endian-ness plays no role; chars are just store in memory one after another in consecutive locations. For example if the string `"johnson"` has been stored (assuming a C string convention) the content of memory would be:

```
0x6A 0x6F 0x68 0x6E 0x73 0x6F 0x6E 0x00
```

Reading this memory content as two 32-bit words would be affected by endian-ness of course, but saying that the machine uses big-endian and asking to display the result in little-endian scheme is nonsense.

In a big endian scheme (e.g. 68k) the two 32-bit words would be `0x6A6F686E` and `0x736F6E00`, in a little-endian scheme (e.g. x86) they would be `0x6E686F6A` and `0x006E6F73`.

Comment: I was also thinking that because I know ASCII isn't affected by endianness but would the characters stay in the same position in the byte address? I understand the content in hex and the switches made between little endian/big endian but would the characters in both big endian/little endian situations be the same?

For example: Big endian characters: J o h n s o n [null] (since there are a total of 8 addresses from 1000-1007)
Little endian characters: J o h n s o n [null]

Basically what I'm asking is if the characters stay in the same position in the byte address or if they are affected.

Comment: @DavisApanasova: endian-ness is about multibyte i.e. about how to store atomically values that are too big to fit in a single byte and the two standard choices are most important bits first (big-endian) or least important bits first (little-endian). It doesn't affect how the machine stores values that fit in a byte. Strings are processed one character at a time and storing an ASCII string is not affected by endianness.

Comment: Alright, so it's same character ordering but the switch between the content in hex between the two.

Thank you 6502!!